# Identify if all values are same within a string

Tags: c#, string, csv, compare

Well I'm stumped on something pretty basic.  I have a string with a set of comma separated values.  Essentially it's something like this:

`public string shapes = circle, circle, square;`

Ultimately this example would return a `false` value in a bool since all 3 values do not match.

I'm looking for the easiest way to compare the values within the one string. So far I've only seen ways of comparing 2 or more strings. I'm hoping i can do this without having  to resort to populating a list or an array.

Comment: You should post some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Please review your question and try to be more clear on what you want to achieve. What exactly would "return a false value in a bool"? If you need to separate values that are in one string, you should look into String.Split [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
static bool ShapeCheck(string shapeString)
{
    var shapes = shapeString.Split(new[] { ',' , ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return shapes.Distinct().Count() == 1;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("circle, circle, square = {0}", ShapeCheck("circle, circle, square"));
Console.WriteLine("circle, circle, circle = {0}", ShapeCheck("circle, circle, circle"));
```

The first would be false, and the second, true.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) function with a comma as the delimiter.

Then assuming that there are leading or tailing whitespaces (as your example suggests), you will need to [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Now you have a populated collections of values from the string.

Then you can use Linq and do a [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and check the length, if the length has changed, there are duplicates.

This is assuming you dont want to know WHAT has been duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `Distinct()` call on a `string[]`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "foo,bar,test";
        Console.WriteLine(DoValuesMatch(str));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool DoValuesMatch(string str)
    {
        var strArr = str.Split(new[] { ',' });
        return strArr.Distinct().Count() == 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks all!  These are all great ways of doing this.  I think John's answer is what I was looking for, but it is good to know that there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the cool, standard answers are already taken...an old school approach:

```
    public string shapes = "circle, circle, square";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        shapes = shapes + ",";
        int comma = shapes.IndexOf(",");
        string value = shapes.Substring(0, comma).Trim();
        shapes = shapes.Replace(value, "").Trim(", ".ToCharArray());
        bool AllTheSame = (shapes.Length == 0);
        if (AllTheSame)
            Console.WriteLine("They are all: " + value);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("They are NOT all the same.");
    }
```